# Error when trying to get last modifed time of a file on a server

Tags: java, android, url, urlconnection

I'm trying to getLastModifed() time of my text file on a server with URLConnection and getting an error.

Here's the code:

```
public static String checkLastModified() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("http://c24871.shared.hc.ru/Extra.txt");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    Date lastModified = new Date(con.getLastModified());

    return dff.format(lastModified);
}
```

If you want more information I'll edit the question.

Comment: `If you want more information I'll edit the question.` Why are you waiting for someone to tell you to do that?

Comment: I don't know what information will be needed, that's why I'm asking

Comment: @CLBack whats the error?

Comment: What is `dff` and what is the error?

Comment: @AbdulKawee the application just closes on Date lastModified = new Date(con.getLastModified());
dff is a format for date

Comment: You should use a try catch block to capture potential Exceptions. The you will see what is going wrong.

Comment: @Robert the application is closing whed I'm trying to get Last modifed time. I'm trying to surround this block with try/catch but none of exeptions can be thrown by this line of code

Comment: `the application is closing `, so run from command-line. If there is an error the JVM will tell you the exception. Without the error/exception nobody can help you.

Comment: I tried to run it from Eclipse,in that case it's working good. idk what I need to do 'coz I'm new to android development

Comment: Code above worked fine for me running in a Java SE 1.8 main(). Last modified was Sun Aug 26 03:51:42 EDT 2018. What Date are you importing?

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to use a `Date`? That class is long outdated (no pun intended) and was always poorly designed. I recommend `Instant.ofEpochMilli(con.getLastModified())`. [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: @Robert, [`getLastModified`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getLastModified--) is not declared to throw any exceptions, and the Java doc linked to doesn’t document any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution.
Need just to put all this function in a Thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            URL url = null;
            try { url = new URL("http://c24871.shared.hc.ru/Extra.txt");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            connection = null;
            try { connection = url.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(connection.getLastModified()));


        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your main problem is that the method `checkLastModified()` does not print anything. Instead it returns the created date String. In the main method where you call `checkLastModified()` you have to print the returned String to see the result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String result = checkLastModified();
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static String checkLastModified() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("http://c24871.shared.hc.ru/Extra.txt");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    Date lastModified = new Date(con.getLastModified());

    SimpleDateFormat dff = new SimpleDateFormat();
    return dff.format(lastModified);
}
```

If you do so you will see on the console

> 26.08.18, 09:51

Comment: No, when i'm trying to run this code from Eclipse it works correctly, but when I'm trying to run it on my smartphone the app is closing with an error. I checked with LogCat, and I know, that problem in `Date lastModified = new Date(con.getLastModified());`

Comment: @CLBlack Right you are trying to run it on Android. Then you shoud edit your question and post your code in which you are calling `checkLastModified()`.